# Is the Heat Kernel an approximation to identity?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I'm trying to figure out if the Heat Kernel is an approximation to identity.

I can't see if the Heat Kernel verifies this:
$$|K_d(x)|\leq A d/ |x|^2 \forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \forall d > 0 $$ 
where the heat kernel equation is
$$K_d(x) = (4 \pi d)^{-1/2} e^{\frac{-x^2}{4d}}. $$

Any idea?

------Edit------

My first attempt was to prove that there was a positive constant $A$, independent from $d$ such that
$$\frac{|x|^2}{d} K_d \leq A $$
but I failed because as $d \to 0$ that function seems to peak to $\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to be whether $(4\pi d)^{-1/2} e^{-\frac{x^2}{4d}} \le \frac{Ad}{|x|^2}$. Stripped of a bit of decoration this is the question whether $e^{-\frac{x^2}{4d}} \le \frac{A d^{3/2}}{|x|^2}$. What happens in case $|x|=1$ and $d \to \infty$?

Comment: im sorry i didnt clarify but Im having trouble specialy when $d \to 0$